# How to download dependencies from behind proxy

Tags: rest, maven, clojure, webapi

I've been trying to follow several different tutorials for building web APIs and web apps using clojure, but I keep receiving the same errors. From googling the errors it seems like the problem is definitely with my network, but I'm having trouble identifying the exact problem and figuring out how to resolve it.

This is the error message I receive every time when I try to run: `lein run`

---

> Could not find artifact org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.2.0-beta1 in central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
>
> Could not find artifact org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.2.0-beta1 in clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/)
>
> Could not find artifact org.clojure:clojure-contrib:jar:1.2.0-beta1 in central (SAME AS FIRST LINK)
>
> Could not find artifact org.clojure:clojure-contrib:jar:1.2.0-beta1 in clojars (SAME AS SECOND LINK)
>
> This could be due to a typo in :dependencies or network issues.
> If you are behind a proxy, try setting the 'http_proxy' environment variable.

---

If anyone knows how to resolve this, please let me know.

Comment: clojure 1.2 is ancient, and the official repo doesn't have the beta for that version any more. The list of available versions is available [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.clojure/clojure)

Comment: The search engine of [maven central works also](http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22org.clojure%22%20AND%20a%3A%22clojure%22)

Comment: I have a secret mission in life to rid the Internet of outdated Clojure tutorials (by updating them or pleading with their authors), could you by chance post a link to the tutorial that told you to use clojure-contrib?

Comment: I changed it to clojure 1.6.0 and clojure-contrib 1.2.0 and the errors went away - thanks so much!

Arthur - here are the tutorials I was following:
http://mmcgrana.github.io/2010/08/clojure-rest-api.html
http://mmcgrana.github.io/2010/07/develop-deploy-clojure-web-applications.html